# Runtime '13' error Type mismatch when trying to programmatically create userform Buttons

Tags: excel, vba

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
 Dim cCont As Control

Set cCont = Me.Controls.Add _
        ("Forms.CommandButton.1", "CopyOf")

    With cCont
        .Caption = "Thanks for creating me"
        .AutoSize = True
    End With

End Sub
```

The above code gives me a Run-Time Error '13" Type Mismatch Error

However, if I do:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
 Me.Controls.Add _
        "Forms.CommandButton.1", "CopyOf"
end sub
```

The command button is created with no errors. I want to create several command buttons, as such, I would like the first piece of code, above, to work. How can I do so?

This is in Excel 2010, Windows 7 x64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    With Controls.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1", "CopyOf")
        .Caption = "Thanks for creating me"
        .AutoSize = True
    End With

    With Controls.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1", "cmd2nd")
        .Top = 25
        .Caption = "Me too..."
        .AutoSize = True
    End With

End Sub
```

Also, if you really want to use the object variable then you would be better served with the specific type:

```
Dim cCont As MSForms.CommandButton
```

Comment: Thank you very much. You're second suggestion worked perfectly for what I want to do. All of the examples that I saw used cCont as control..